# C - Add elements of a 2D char Array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to add the rows and columns of a 2D char array. So that they form a word. I know how to add the elements of a 2D int array and tried to implement a similar solution here. However it does not work.

```
Example input:
a  b  c  d
e  f  g  h
i  j  k  l

Example Output:
Row 1 word = abcd
Row 2 word = efgh
Row 3 word = ijkl
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int size;
    char wordR;

    printf("Enter size:\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    char word[size][size];

    //Entering the matrix
    for (int k = 0; k < (size); ++k){
        for (int j = 0; j < (size); ++j){
            printf("Enter letter: ");
            scanf(" %c",&word[k][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            printf(" %c",word[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Adding row elements
    for(k = 0; k < size; ++k){
        for(p = 0; p < size; ++p){
            wordR += size[k][p];
        }
        printf("Word of the %i row is = %c\n",k,wordR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the refined code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int size;

    printf("Enter size:\n");
    scanf("%u", &size); // size is unsigned, so use %u.

    char word[size][size];
    char wordR[size + 1]; // +1 for the terminating '\0'
    wordR[size] = '\0'; // wordR[size] will always be '\0'.

    int  i, j;

    //Entering the matrix
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < (size); ++j){
            printf("Enter letter: ");
            scanf(" %c",&word[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            printf(" %c",word[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Adding row elements
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            wordR[j] = word[i][j];
        }
        printf("Word of the %i row is = %s\n", i, wordR);
    }
}
```

It is the statement

```
wordR += size[k][p];
```

that prevents your code from working properly. Probably you think this will magically concatenate a string, but unfortunately, it's just adding up the ascii value of characters in `size[k]`. Any way, `wordR` is defined as a `char` in your code, and how can a single `char` contain a whole string (namely array of `char`)?

There are also some minor problems in your code, which I've made some change on. See the comments for details.

Comment: @AlterMann Oh, I'm going to fix that. Thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 2):

> wordR += size[k][p];

This doesn't work as you think it does.
It is not a way to concatenate strings in C.

Besides `wordT` is a `char`, which means it is single character.
What you are doing above, is doing plain math of ASCII codes of characters.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of major problems: First of all the variable `wordR` is a *single* character, not actually a "word". You need an *array* of characters to create a string. Second problem is that even if you use an array of characters, you can't use `+=` to append to the array.

You also have to remember that strings in C are zero-terminated. So a string of four characters actually contains *five* character including the terminator character `'\0'`. In your case you need an array of `size + 1` characters.

Comment: How would I achieve concatenation of the rows then if using Arrays is not a viable option?

Comment: @robinhood46 If you can't use a string for each row, then simply don't use a string. Just print the letters in the matrix without spacing between them and it will look just like a string. *Or* create a string to begin with, i.e. have `word[size][size + 1]` and remember to append the terminator for each row.

Comment: Wow, I was so obsessed with creating words, thinking a needed to concatenate a string whereas I could just focus on the spacing of the matrix. Thanks, I know what I need to do now!